# "c'est celui qui..." or "il est celui qui..."

Tags: pronoms, pronoms-relatifs, pronoms-personnels

When saying "He’s the one who...", is it more natural to say "c'est celui qui..." than "il est celui qui..."? I’m so familiar with the "c'est" being used with the meaning of "it is" that its another meaning "he/she is" does not come naturally to me.

> Albert ? De nous tous, je trouve que **c'est celui qui** a le moins changé depuis des années.
>
> Albert ? De nous tous, je trouve qu'**il est celui qui** a le moins changé depuis des années.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- *Je trouve que c'est celui qui a le moins changé...* is by far the more natural way to state it.
- *Je trouve qu'il est celui qui a le moins changé...*, while not being grammatically incorrect, is unnatural and would likely be avoided in a casual conversation by a native French speaker for being too emphatic. Paradoxically, that form is much more likely to be used by non native French speakers because, as you wrote, many are reluctant to use ***ce*** to refer to people.

  For example, *Ils sont français* is fine but *Ils sont des Français*, while fully understandable is very unidiomatic. All native will correct it to *Ce sont des Français*.

Comment: To @jlliagre: "Paul croit qu'**il est** un grand artiste mais **c'est** juste un peintre amateur." vs "Paul croit que **c'est** un grand artiste mais **il est** juste un peintre amateur." I assume that the first sentence makes it clear that the said artist is Paul himself whereas the second makes it sound as if the artist in question is someone else. Am I correct here? Merci.

Comment: Yes, although in the second case, the most common form would be *Paul croit que c'est un grand artiste mais c'est juste un peintre amateur* or better *...mais ce n'est qu'un peintre amateur*.

Comment: A way to avoid any misunderstanding would be "Paul croît être un grand artiste mais...". Without context, that's clear, while your sentences could both be ambiguous...